# Paste Intercept event failure

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, paste

I want to intercept a paste event for a FIRST NAME textbox so that if the user pastes "Joe Smith, PhD", they will get "Joe" in the FIRST NAME textbox, and they will see "Smith, PhD" in the LAST NAME textbox.  Instead, what I get is "Joe Smith,PhDJoe" in FIRST NAME textbox, and "Smith, PhD" in LAST NAME textbox.  I added a messagebox as a breakpoint for me and if I uncomment that line, the msgbox displays and then the sub works perfectly.  So, is this a timing issue (Windows 10/VS2015 if that matters)?

There are many posts on how to intercept paste events, and my code below is based on that.  What am I doing wrong?

```
Public Class test

 Private Sub TBfname_PASTE(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TBFname.KeyDown

    Dim Pasting As String = Clipboard.GetText()

    If e.Modifiers = Keys.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.V Then

        Dim SplitWhere As Int64 = 0
        Dim words = Pasting.Split(" "c)
        Dim firstWord = words(0)

        If Pasting.Contains(" ") Then

            SplitWhere = Pasting.IndexOf(" ")
            Dim LN As String = ""

            Dim long2 As Int64 = Pasting.Length - SplitWhere - 1
            If long2 > 0 Then
                LN = Pasting.Substring(SplitWhere + 1, long2)
                TBLname.Text = LN
            End If

            '              MsgBox(Pasting & " vs " & TBFname.Text)

            TBFname.Text = firstWord

        End If
        e.Handled = True

    End If

 End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could to is declare `firstword` as a `Form` level variable

```
Private firstWord As String
```

and then assign it in `TBfname_KeyDown`

```
firstWord = words(0)
```

Then in the `KeyUp` event re-assign `TBfname.Text`

```
Private Sub TBfname_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TBfname.KeyUp
    TBfname.Text = firstWord
End Sub
```

Comment: This works, so I'm all set, but I am puzzled why my code appended instead of replacing text.

Comment: @Matt - Not sure why the data is appending.  For some reason the `TextChanged` event seems to be doing this.  If you place `Application.DoEvents()` before `TBfname.Text = firstWord` in your original version it works.